# Dell XPS 13 Ubuntu 20.04 select audio device no sound when no selection made (or pressing escape)

Tags: sound, 20.04

When inserting into the headphone jack a gnome graphical selection appears and by either not pressing anything or pressing escape there is no sound coming out of the headphones. In the Sound settings, it indicates that the headphones are selected, however, no sound is coming out. Everything works when I select option 1 (i.e. "Headphones") by clicking on it. Is anyone else getting this issue with Ubuntu 20.04.

I didn't have this problem with Ubuntu 18.04 I plugged in my microphone-less headphones hit escape and away I went listening to music.

Is anyone else getting this issue or does anyone know a good work-around for me just select option 1 (no mic headphones)?

EDIT: It seems its a bug that as of current has not been reported in launchpad. If anybody is experiencing the same issue it would be greater if you can add an alsa config report by running: `wget -O alsa-info.sh http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh && chmod +x ./alsa-info.sh && ./alsa-info.sh` and adding the resulting URL in the comment section in the following link: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/690501

Hopefully it will be picked up as a bug report.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on XPS 15, Kubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I came across this extension https://extensions.gnome.org/review/8501
It defaults to using something similar to the escape key. If only there was a way to edit it to default to one of the 3 options.

Comment: I’m having the issue as well with 20.04 and did not find a solution yet be it on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu or elsewhere.

Comment: @arkhi Ok, It looks like there is a private bug #1875597 that describes the issue. I can't see it. Judging by the path launchpad has should be https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1875597

Comment: See [comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1871329/comments/12) by Hui Wang at  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1871329

Comment: This bug seems to be back since last week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 2020-06-10 this bug seems to be fixed just update by running this in terminal `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

I don't know what caused the fix see suggestions in the comments at https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/690501

Answer (score 12):

`alsactl restore` causes sound to come out from both laptop speaker and headphones simultaneously.

To get sound from the wired headphones one has to open Sound Settings, go to Input and select Internal Microphone Built-in Audio every time headphones are connected to the 3.5mm jack. Observed the same on Dell XPS 13 and Dell 75-series gaming laptops.

Looks like a 20.04 bug. Reproducible in Cinnamon and KDE Plasma DEs. 
In 18.04 there was no such issue.

Comment: Thank you for confirming this. You have summarized the issue nicely. Hopefully, this will be patched. Since this appears in other DEs is this bug coming from the new updates to the Kernal and capability with some of Dells Sound card?

Comment: Thanks for this George, your work-around sorts it out nicely.
Does anybody know if this is reported on launchpad? I haven't found anything.

Comment: I have placed a question on launchpad but no report yet. See here: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/690501

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by switching to Konsole and running:

alsactl restore

Comment: This is a solution. Thank you! Although I have to run this every time I plugin. Any idea’s how to automate this command when I plug in headphones?

Comment: I think there is a problem with this solution. After it, sound comes both from my laptop speaker and headphones...

Answer (score 4):

What fixes it for me is:

- Go to sound preferences
- Click on the input tab
- Under connector, choose `Internal microphone`

Comment: Do you go to sound preferences every time you plugin? If so it shouldn't be the case. It should always default to Internal microphone unless Audio Select Device --> Headset (thus using headset microphone). See the answer by George.